# How To Properly <section> and <article> a multi-topic blog index?

Tags: html

If I have a blog index page that is going to contain news, reviews, and videos, each in their own 'section' does it make sense to have each group of excerpts defined as their own section such as:

```
<section id="news">
<h2>Section Title</h2>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
</section>

<section id="reviews">
<h2>Section Title</h2>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
</section>

<section id="videos">
<h2>Section Title</h2>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
<article> ... an article excerpt here ... </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5) says:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content.
>
> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication.

So the way you use `<article>` and `<section>` to structure your content is fully compliant with the specification.